Linux kernel ignores resumewait option, resulting in HORN configuration
I'm having trouble with my Linux (Debian GNU/Linux) system. Problem is that I currently have a HORN (Hibernate only, resume never) configuration: I can only hibernate but I cannot resume. Even worse than that, if I try to resume my system just performs a regular boot and my hibernation data is lost.
To prevent this, I added the resumewait option to my kernel command line in /boot/grub/grub.cfg:
linux   /vmlinuz-5.10.0-28-amd64 root=UUID=********-****-****-****-************ ro quiet splash resumewait

This is also the command line my system was booted with, as can be seen here:
$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.10.0-28-amd64 root=UUID=********-****-****-****-************ ro quiet splash resumewait

STill, there was no resumption from hibernate. All of my data from the hibernation image was lost. Instead, there is this in /var/log/messages:
Apr 10 17:23:13 * kernel: [20005.276752] PM: hibernation: hibernation entry
Apr 10 20:56:03 * kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x28, date = 2019-11-12

So my system was first hibernated, then performed a regular boot. With swap disabled.
My swap partition is on a separate hard drive and I understand that this separate hard drive is a bit old and can be a bit slow when booting the system. But I have resumewait in my kernel parameters which should prevent a regular boot if my swap partition is unavailable. So why is this happening? And what should I do to make resumewait actually work on my system?
